# iOS/iPhone didSelectRowAtIndexPath self.navigationController pushViewController not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I am surely losing my mind. I have coded what I assume to be a fairly standard usage of the 
`didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method here:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    if (row == 0){
        BuildingDescriptionViewController *buildingDescriptionViewController = [[BuildingDescriptionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BuildingDescriptionViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        NSLog(@"self.navigationController0 is %@", self.navigationController ? @"not nil" : @"nil");
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:buildingDescriptionViewController animated:YES];
        [buildingDescriptionViewController release];
    }
    else if (row == 1){
        PostCommentViewController *buildingCommentViewController = [[PostCommentViewController alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"self.navigationController1 is %@", self.navigationController ? @"not nil" : @"nil");
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:buildingCommentViewController animated:YES];
        [buildingCommentViewController release];
    }
}
```

The NSLog informs that the navigationController is NOT nil, but nothing else happens. Neither viewController appears. In fact, just the NSLog occurs. Is there some esoteric usage I am missing? I have also tried [self presentModalViewController:buildingDescriptionViewController animated:YES]; and nothing happened. I could really use some assistance.
Thanks.

UPDATE:
Output per Sailesh's suggestion below

> 2011-06-27 18:02:56.370 something[16331:207] buildingdecriptionviewcontrollerinit
>   2011-06-27 18:02:56.370 something[16331:207] ViewControllers before pushing: (
>     "BuildingProfileViewController: 0x7e89680"
>   )
>
> 2011-06-27 18:02:56.370 something[16331:207] ViewControllers after pushing: (
>      "BuildingProfileViewController: 0x7e89680>",
>      "BuildingDescriptionViewController: 0x7e73d30"
>   )
>
> 2011-06-27 18:03:15.843 something[16331:207] buildingdecriptionviewcontrollerinit
>
> 2011-06-27 18:03:15.844 something[16331:207] ViewControllers before pushing: (
>      "BuildingProfileViewController: 0x7e89680",
>      "BuildingDescriptionViewController: 0x7e73d30"
>   )
>
> 2011-06-27 18:03:15.844 something[16331:207] ViewControllers after pushing: (
>      "BuildingProfileViewController: 0x7e89680"
>      "BuildingDescriptionViewController: 0x7e73d30"
>      "BuildingDescriptionViewController: 0xcc2c8e0"
>   )

Comment: did you make sure buildingDescriptionViewController/buildingCommentViewController is not nil?

Comment: buildingDescriptionViewController is NOT nil, but even if it was wouldn't there be some result? It's perplexing.

Comment: Maybe my situation isn't clear. When I select the row the NSLog displays the correct row, but that is the only result. There is nothing else that happens. It doesn't blowup. It just doesn't push to the next viewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I was confused by the fact that the self.navigationController wasn't NIL. The issue was that the tableView had been added as a subview. I fixed it by pushing its viewController onto the navigation stack. Thanks to everyone that replied.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Can you please me explain me in detail? I have three subviews as uitableview in my uiview class. I would like to change the screen if i click the table cell.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the view controller is really being pushed into the navigation stack.

To check, do this:

```
NSLog("ViewControllers before pushing: %@", self.navigationController.viewControllers);
[self.navigationController pushViewController:....];
NSLog("ViewControllers after pushing: %@", self.navigationController.viewControllers);
```

The output in the console will be some adresses of the viewControllers, but you will at least know the number of viewControllers in the navigation stack before and after pushing viewController. If they ARE getting pushed, then the problem must be in some other part of your code, I suppose.

Please reply with the output.

Comment: Thanks Sailesh. They are indeed getting pushed.

Comment: I meant to say that I posted the output above.

Comment: Then the error is certainly somewhere else. Check if the viewDidLoad (and similar viewWill.. and viewDid...) methods are being called for BuildingDescriptionViewController. You may be doing something that is making your rootViewController the active viewController.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved my issue by calling any view method or property.

```
childController = [[YouTubeLaunch alloc] initWithNibName:@"YouTubeView" bundle:nil];
        childController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

I also had the same issue for the last 3 days. Although the `viewController` is getting added but only `RootViewController` is coming up but not `YouTubeEmbedPlayer` .

2011-06-27 19:53:17.677 [1263:207] `ViewControllers` before pushing: ( "", "", "", "" ) 2011-06-27 19:53:22.496 [1263:207] ViewControllers before pushing: ( "", "", "", "", "" )

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. I tried that and I did get to viewDidLoad but I still don't see the view. It's very strange. I did add the controllers view as a subview and was able to see it, but that's not ideal (of course). I will keep at it.